# Wordpress Comment form simple

Tags: wordpress, forms, comments

I am working with wordpress from scratch and problem is that i just don't know how to add comment form. It can be basic comment form (email + username + post your comment) with some style.

Everytime I try to run plugin it's not working. Don't know why plugins aren't working in single.php. Mybe I code something wrong?

Aprreciate you, thank you for your time and for helping me. I am still beginner as you can see ;)

Comment: I tried allot of comment form ( HTML + PHP) non of them worked perfectly...

Comment: Please post your plugin's code.

Comment: Plugin is called WP-Ajaxify-Comments (hooks into your current theme and adds AJAX functionality to the comment form.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you also look at your settings and see if you are allowing comments? In wp-admin dashboard click on Settings-> Discussion and see what your comment setting are set to.

Comment: Hey, I have same as this.http://codex.wordpress.org/images/5/55/options-discussion1.png